# Changing a user's password in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

After creating a user, how do you change their password? Is there something in the Admin UI to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset a user’s password, use the following command:

```
cockroach user set [username] --password [certificate flags]
```

You’ll then be prompted at the CLI to enter a new password.

There's no way to change a user's password via the Admin UI.

Comment: There is no subcommand `cockroach user` in latest version of cockroach

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter `cockroach sql` and alter user: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/alter-user.html#change-a-users-password

`ALTER USER <user> WITH PASSWORD '<password>'`